# Disabling fixyear option causes margin year to appear for all bibitems of the same year

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

[image: 1]

The year 2021 appears twice although it appears once when setting `fixyear=true`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{aldaoudeyeh2021new,
    title={A new method to fit logistic functions with wind turbines power curves using manufacturer datasheets},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, {Al-Motasem} Ihssan and Alzaareer, Khaled and Harasis, Salman and {Al-Odat}, Zeyad and Obeidat, Mohammad and Mansour, Ayman and Wu, Di and Salem, Qusay},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={16},
    number={2},
    year={2021},
    month={12},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1049/rpg2.12309}
}

@article{alzaareer2021sensitivity,
    title={Sensitivity Analysis for Voltage Stability Considering Voltage Dependent Characteristics of Loads and DGs},
    author={Alzaareer, Khaled and Saad, Maarouf and Mehrjerdi, Hasan and Salem, Qusay and Harasis, Salman and Aldaoudeyeh, {Al-Motasem} Ihssan and Al-Masri, Hussein MK},
    journal={IEEE Access},
    year={2021},
    month={11},
    volume={9},
    number={1},
    pages={156437-156450},
    publisher={IEEE},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1109/ACCESS.2021.3129135}
}
    
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight, fixyear=false, marginyear=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\plauthorname[{Al-Motasem} Ihssan]{Aldaoudeyeh}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Journal Articles}, type=article]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in the next version (2.6). In the meantime, you can use the style file from the repository: https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/raw/master/publist.bbx